# How to change certain values in a torch tensor based on an index in another torch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch, openai-gym

This is an issue I'm running while `convertinf` DQN to Double DQN for the `cartpole` problem. I'm getting close to figuring it out.

```
tensor([0.1205, 0.1207, 0.1197, 0.1195, 0.1204, 0.1205, 0.1208, 0.1199, 0.1206,
        0.1199, 0.1204, 0.1205, 0.1199, 0.1204, 0.1204, 0.1203, 0.1198, 0.1198,
        0.1205, 0.1204, 0.1201, 0.1205, 0.1208, 0.1202, 0.1205, 0.1203, 0.1204,
        0.1205, 0.1206, 0.1206, 0.1205, 0.1204, 0.1201, 0.1206, 0.1206, 0.1199,
        0.1198, 0.1200, 0.1206, 0.1207, 0.1208, 0.1202, 0.1201, 0.1210, 0.1208,
        0.1205, 0.1205, 0.1201, 0.1193, 0.1201, 0.1205, 0.1207, 0.1207, 0.1195,
        0.1210, 0.1204, 0.1209, 0.1207, 0.1187, 0.1202, 0.1198, 0.1202])
tensor([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True])
```

As you can see here two tensors.
The `first` has the q values I want
but,
some values need to be changed to zeros because of it an end state.
The `second` tensor shows where it will be zeros.

At the index where the Boolean value is false is the equivalent spot for where the upper tensor needs to be zeros.
I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.where) - `torch.where(condition, x, y)`

**Ex.:**

```py
>>> x = tensor([0.2853, 0.5010, 0.9933, 0.5880, 0.3915, 0.0141, 0.7745,  
                0.0588, 0.4939, 0.0849])
>>> condition = tensor([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  
                        False, False, False])

>>> # It's equivalent to `torch.where(condition, x, tensor(0.0))`
>>> x.where(condition, tensor(0.0))
tensor([0.0000, 0.5010, 0.9933, 0.5880, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.7745,  
        0.0000, 0.0000,0.0000])
```

Comment: Direct official link: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html#torch.where

Answer (score 4):

If your above tensor is the value tensor and the bottom one is the decision tensor, then

```
value_tensor[decision_tensor==False] = 0
```

Moreover, you could also convert them to numpy arrays and perform the same operation and it should work.